# Probability of observing car in particular time

Tags: probability

You are standing beside a road watching cars pass by. The probability that you see a car pass by in 1 minute is 1/4. What is the probability that you see a car pass by in 30 seconds?

My Answer: P(seeing a car in 1 min) = P(either see a car in first 30 or second 30s) = P(see a car in first 30 seconds) + P(see a car in second 30 seconds) which implies 2p = 1/4, hence p =1/8, where p(see a car in 30 seconds). Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Have you been studying the Poisson distribution lately?

Answer (score 2):

In order to produce an answer, one has to make a reasonable mathematical model.  We will assume that the numbers of cars one sees in disjoint time periods are independent, and that the distribution of the number of cars depends only on the length of the time interval.

We interpret "seeing a car" in a particular time period as meaning we see *at least one* car in that time period.

Let $A$ be the event we see **no car** in the first half-minute period of observation, and let $B$ be the event we see no car in the second half-minute period.  Let $p=\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)$.

The probability of no cars in the one-minute period is $p^2$, which we are told is $3/4$. Thus $p=\sqrt{3/4}$, and the probability of seeing at least one car in a half-minute period is $1-\sqrt{3/4}$.

Comment: Very nice explanation to an apparently tricky question. +1. If you could also add the exact flaw in OPs argument, that would be great. It would help many others who think similarly

Comment: @Shailesh: One can think of OP's argument as correct for a very different model, and one that is less plausible. If we are on a deserted road, and know that at most one car will pass through, then we can think of the events $C$: **the car** passes through in the first $30$ seconds, and $D$: the car passes through in the second $30$ seconds as disjoint. Under that model, probability $1/8$ is right.