# Probability of observing at least 1 car on the high in a given timeframe

Tags: probability

I'm struggling to understand the problem, and I think the problem statement itself may be a bit ambiguous and open to interpretation:

**Problem statement: If the probability of observing at least 1 car on the road in any 20minute time interval is $k$, then what is the probability of observing at least 1 car during any 5minute time interval? Assume that the probability of seeing a car at any moment is uniform for the entire 20minutes.**

Question 1: I am confused by the wording "any 5minute interval." Could this be reasonably interpreted as "what is the probability of observing at least 1 car among all 5minute intervals, i.e., the union of there being at least 1 car in all 5 minute intervals?" If so, then isn't the answer simply $k$ based on this interpretation?

Question 2: Could this question be reasonable interpreted as "what is the probability that **a** 5 minute interval has at least 1 car?" If so, then isn't the probability simply $\frac{k}{4}$? The problem statement states that the the probability is uniform at any moment, so if $k$ is the probability for 20minutes, then any 5 minute interval should just have a probability that is $\frac{k}{4}$?

Question 3: I read Andre Nicolas comment and solution on [Probability of observing car in particular time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483164/probability-of-observing-car-in-particular-time). The comment about the Poisson distribution could be applicable in my case if the problem statement hadn't stated that the probability is uniform across the 20minute timeframe, so I don't think the poisson distribution applies here. His solution matches the one given below.

Okay, so now the solution that is given is based on breaking the 20minute interval into 4 non-overlapping time intervals. Because of uniformity, the probability of observing a car in any 5-minute is the same amongst the four 5minute intervals. Let $p$ denote this probability. The probability that we do not observe a car in a minute interval is $1-p$. The probability that we don't observe a car in all four 5minute intervals is $(1-p)^4 = k \implies p = 1-k^{0.25}$. Obviously, this is very different from what my 2 interpretations in Questions 1 and 2.

I paraphrased the solution, so I'm attaching an image below of the actual textbook solution

[image]

## Edit: After reading Andre's answer, and rereading the problem statement, I think I realize why my Question 2 solution is wrong. The problem statement states **at least 1 car** in the 20minute interval. My solution was solving a different problem and assumed there is a single car in the 20minute interval.

Comment: That's right.  The book's solution assumes that the observations in different $5$-minute intervals are independent, but it doesn't seem to say so anywhere.  If there is a single car, or some limited number of cars, then this isn't so.  We have to assume a constant stream of traffic.

Comment: @saulspatz Hmm right, it seems the book assumes that independency, but that doesn't seem to be intuitive to me. If we have four 5-minute intervals, then intuitively, I feel like the probability of not observing a car in, say, in the 15-20minute interval depends on the probability of not observing a car in the 0-5, 5-10, and 10-15minute intervals.

Comment: @saulspatz On second thought, the book's last sentence in the problem statement states "Assume that the probability of seeing a car in any moment is uniform (constant) for the entire 20minutes." Doesn't that implicate independence? When I read it again, it sounds like it's saying that the probability of seeing a car for a 5minute interval does not affect the probability of seeing a car in another non-overlapping 5minute interval.

Comment: If you think of sitting at the side of the highway during a reasonable busy time of day, so that the traffic passes at a constant rate, then independence seems reasonable to me.  On the other hand, if we're sitting by a private road, and we know that only $6$ cars ever use the road, then what you say sounds more applicable.

Comment: @saulspatz Right I understand that that is the case for a single car, but what I meant was that the problem statement said that the probability of seeing A car is constant at any moment, and not a specific single car. So it now sounds like it's saying there's an independent stream of cars.

Comment: Well, yes, that's what they mean, but I don't think they said it well.  I think when you learn about the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), the assumptions will be stated more precisely.